# How to add path to .env file and use it?

Tags: node.js, path, config, require, dotenv

I wanted to put the path in here:

```
const serviceAccount = require("./service_account.json");
```

into a .env file like this:

```
PATH="./service_account.json"
```

and getting the like this:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const serviceAccount = require(process.env.PATH);
```

error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\LINQPad5;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\santo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\santo\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\santo\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Users\santo\AppData\Roaming\npm'
Require stack:
- C:\internal_bestmposlite-dashboard\BestMPOS-Lite\list_user_data.js
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing you can do is change the name of the variable.

Use something like `path` instead of `PATH`.

Or `File`, `FILE`, etc.

the `PATH` variable in env files will not show what you put inside of the `.env` file.

**Here is an example:**

`.env` file

```
PATH=./service_account.js
path=./service_account.js
```

`index.js` file

```js
require('dotenv').config();

console.log(`process.env.PATH ` + process.env.PATH);
console.log(`\n`)
console.log(`process.env.path ` + process.env.path);

const Function = require(process.env.path);

console.log(Function)
```

Output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Create .env file at root folder and put your all variables inside .env file.
You can also give relative path of .env file like that:

```
require('dotenv').config({path:'pathToENV'})
```